# IOS: Image from assets folder not/shown in device OR simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I'm experiencing some troubles on one of my projects.
Shortly I've made a project using storyboards and now I'm using xibs (plus some programmatic views) and I'm also using Xcode 10 + macOS mojave (with the new update). Thing is I have an image that I have to put as a header on a view (unfortunately this view is a hamburger/side menu view or however you want to call it). I made everything to work, but the thing is I didn't want to rely on the IB and just drop an image and underneath a table view.
Firstly I put there the image view and it was ok on device, but on simulator you couldn't see that image, saying that the "menuImage" (how it was named) couldn't be found in the nib "com.comp.comp" which was weird because the image was in the assets.
Then I just removed that despicable view and made the table view cover the whole view. I created programatically a headerView and an imageView and added the imageView as a subview to the headerView then I set the tableView.headerView to be = to that headerView I made, with an image inside. On simulator it was filling the **whole** view  with that image, which made and still makes no sense, and on device you could only see a blank view. If I was setting that headerView I created the backgroundColor to .red I was able to see the red header inside the table view. I could set that height to be 10 or 200 and it was perfect, but when I wanted to put the image it was just white. I tried setting the tableView's, headerView's and imageView's backgrounds to .clear, but didn't work.
Even dropping an image view inside the table view within the IB didn't work. Now I'm using the first solution, the image view on top of the table view.
Now I'm gonna finish this up (sorry :'( )... I did delete the app and restarted the iPhone and repeat this "solution" several times, also did create a new project and put manually the images I needed in the assets.
I really looked up on stack overflow but didn't find anyone to experience the same issue as me, so not any solution to it.
I'm sorry for the long post; I hope you guys have at least an idea or hint or anything.
EDIT: As I said about the code snippet...here it is:

```
private func setupHeaderView() {
        let image = UIImage(named: "menuImage")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 150))

        headerView.addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true

        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
    }
```

Even by commenting translatesAutoresizingMask and those 4 lines with the anchor constraints, I wasn't able to see the image. Now I have an imageView right on top of the table view (did this in the xib file) and I'm not able to see the image on the device, but on the simulator I can.

Comment: Are you sure you are including the images in your target?  Select the image file in the project navigator (on the left) in Xcode, and in the File Inspector pane (on the right), you should see a section for Target Membership.  Make sure you have selected all your build targets, otherwise the image files will not get packaged as part of the application bundle.

Comment: Ok...i'll check today and come back with an answer. Thank you very much :D

Comment: @wottle Hi..sorry for the delayed reply. I checked and in the target membership is my build target, the only one. Like all the other images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post is difficult to comprehend as no code was posted nor screenshots if you used storyboard, i.e. both leading to complications in your description. Here is what can be done.

An image from image assets is generally used by an

```
var imageView = UIImageView(frame: yourFrame)
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "nameFromAssets")
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit //This helps keep the image original aspect ratio
self.view.addSubview(imageView) // Or whatever view you are using
```

Or by using Storyboard

1) Place an imageView on the screen somewhere and organize it as you'd like (constraints, etc)

2) In the Inspector, choose the image you want for it using the dropdown

3) Provide the contentMode you'd like

Comment: Thank you for you interest. Well I'm using xibs, but the thing is I wanted to add a header to the table view programmatic. I created an imageView with that image and I added it as a subview to a header that I also created in code and then assigned that view to the tableView.tableHeaderView. I'm gonna post some code today. If you can please just take a look whenever you can... Domo arigato! :D

Comment: Hi @impression7vx
Can you please tell me if there's anything at all regarding this issue of not being able to see the image? I mean it's really weird...if you know anything at all it would be useful. Thank you in advance

Comment: Try adding imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: Well that property is false by default...but I even tried it, but no results... In simulator the whole table view is filled by that image even though you see now the code, and on device you cannot see anything but a white space, where the image was supposed to be.
Even by looking into the view hierarchy I'm able to see the image view, but not the images! wtf? I mean...either there's something wrong with me or with me...

Comment: According to the class reference for UIImage, it says that You should avoid creating UIImage objects that are greater than 1024 x 1024 in size.
I think here's the problem...if so, I shall update my question with an answer.

Comment: I've noticed that I, like a loser, didn't create an imageView by passing a frame into the constructor, but by passing the image...the thing is I've done some tests also on the xcode 10 BETA and the results with the same code basis were pretty different than the results on xcode 9 (latest version)...
Btw guys, do not EVER use any beta software from apple...inclusiv the mac os mojave or any other newer mac os that's still in beta. Thank you